# My GCP compute instance isn't receiving any port traffic

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform, port, localhost, cloud-computing

> const express = require('express') const app = express() const port =
> 9093
>
> app.get('/', (req, res) => {   res.send('Hello World!') })
>
> app.listen(port, () => {   console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`) })

this is node sample code

[Request is sent successfully through local host but timeouts to connecting through the instance IP.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRduN.png)

[This is the firewall rule. I have tried targeting applying rule to the instance Label. Also tried applying it to all. None worked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIlOD.png)

[port receives the requested ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZBHi.png)

Comment: My guess is that you did not assign the tag `http-server` to the instance's network tag. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/add-remove-network-tags Note: you changed the port number for `http-server` to 9093. Leave that rule as port 80 and create a new firewall rule and tag for port 9093.

Comment: I have tried that too. The same result for my other instances too. I created a newer instance to rule other thing out. The instance does respond to every port used in NodeJS code, didn't even had to add rules for it.

Comment: Setting the network tags is a requirement, not something you try. Edit your question with details on the VM's network tags and the matching Firewall rule. Check if you have the UFW firewall enabled.